# Existe una forma posible el acceso de una base de datos desde Blogger

Tags: php, javascript, base-de-datos

son una gran comunidad de ayuda y aprendo mucho... Mi pregunta es después de investigar en muchos sitios si hay manera de llamar a una base de datos desde blogger? quiero comprar un complementó, pero este requiere de una base de datos, no estoy seguro si pueda hacer que funcione, si existe algún método.

Aquí les dejo el enlace para darse una mejor idea:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codecanyon.net/item/reaction-button-jquery-plugin-makes-everything-reactable/22430347)

Comment: Mediante un endpoint podrías acceder a la base de datos usando javascript.

Comment: [Según esta respuesta](https://support.google.com/blogger/thread/17092483?hl=en), no es posible. Si Blogger te deja personalizar código Javascript, una posibilidad sería usar Firebase, que tiene un SDK para conectar desde el cliente. Pero Firebase no es propiamente una Base de Datos, puedes guardar documentos allí (que son realmente estructuras JSON) y obtener/usar los datos guardados en ellos desde el cliente.